# Finding the length of the curve $5y^3 = x^2$ that lies inside the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 6$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem:
Find the length of the curve $5y^3 = x^2$ that lies inside the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 6$.
Answer:

Now we need to find the points of intersection.
\begin{align*}
x^2 &= 6 - y^2 \\
5y^3 &= 6 - y^2 \\
5y^3 + y^2 - 6 &= 0 \\
(5y^2 + 6y + 6) (y - 1) &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Hence $y = 1$ is one solution. I claim the equation $5y^2 + 6y + 6 = 0$ has no real roots. When $y = 1$, the two corresponding
x values are $\pm \sqrt{5}$.
\begin{align*}
y^3 &= \frac{ x^2 }{5} \\
y &= \frac{ x^{ \frac{1}{3} } }{ 5^{\frac{1}{3}}} \\
y' &=  \frac{ x^{ - \frac{2}{3} } }{ 3 \left(  5^{\frac{1}{3}} \right) } 
\end{align*}
Let $L$ be the length we seek.
\begin{align*}
L &= \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1 + \left( y' \right) ^2} \,\,\, dx \\
L &=  \int_{a}^{b}
 \sqrt{1 + \left(  \frac{ x^{ - \frac{2}{3} } }{ 3 \left(  5^{\frac{1}{3}} \right) }  \right) ^2} \,\,\, dx \\
L &= \int_{a}^{b}
 \sqrt{1 + \left(  \frac{ x^{ - \frac{4}{3} } }{ 9 \left(  5^{\frac{2}{3}} \right) }  \right) } \,\,\, dx
\end{align*}
I do not know how to integrate. Am I right so far? How do I integrate it?

Comment: You made a mistake solving for $y$. It should be $y = \frac{x^{2/3}}{5^{1/3}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a small error.

$y^3 = \frac {x^2}{5}\\
y = \frac {x^{\frac 23}}{5^\frac 13}\\
y' = \frac 23 \frac {x^{-\frac 13}}{5^\frac 13}$

But that isn't really your problem... What if, instead of integrating with respect to $x,$ you integrate with respect to $y$?

The lower bound of $y = 0$, the upper bound is 1.
The curve is symmetric across the line $x = 0.$  We will take $x\ge 0$ and double the integral.

$x = \sqrt {5} y^{\frac 32}\\
x' = \frac {3\sqrt 5}{2} y^\frac 12\\
x'^2 = \frac {45}{4}y$

$2\int_0^1 \left (\sqrt {1 + \frac {45}{4} y}\right) \ dy$

Comment: The correct answer is: $\frac{134}{27}$

Comment: @Doug M I think you have the wrong value for $x'^2$. I think it should be $\frac{45y}{4}$.

Comment: The book's answer is $\frac{134}{27}$.